# How to skip validation rule in trigger in "onafterinsert" without inserting any field on object?

Tags: salesforce-id, salesforce2salesforce

i need to skip validation onAfterInsert method without adding additional field on object.

Comment: Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Please **[edit]** your post with additional detail.

Comment: hey adrian sorry if u didn't get my problem. i am new here and dont know much about this. thanx for the links will go through it.i have mentioned my issue in comments with nachiket.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding any custom logic you can't skip the validation rule for Triggers.
Following is the order of execution.

- System Validation rule (required field, field format)
- Triggers are executed (Before Triggers)
- Custom Validation rules are checked
- After Triggers are executed
- Assignment Rules are executed
  etc, so once before triggers gets executed Salesforce will automatically execute validation rules.You need to have custom logic defined to skip the validation rule.

> You can create a checkbox field lets say "ByPass Validation"
>  Set
>   this field to TRUE in before trigger
>  Add condition of checkbox
>   "ByPass Validation" in your validation rule stating not to execute validation rule ,when  "ByPass
>   Validation" is set to true

Comment: hey nachiket, in my scenario actually i have two objects assessment_template__C and assessment, now there is copyConfig field in both the objects and i need to copy assessment template field value to assessment object field.but there is also validation rule on assessment which says that if assessment in inprogress state u can not update that field. but when i insert assessment i need to cop template value to assessment and it is firing validation rule as in onafter insert assessment will be in inprogress state.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about your requirement, what exactly you want to achieve when you say you want to bypass the validation rule so that  I can help you better, please describe your use case in more detail!

Comment: You can't run away from validation rules, unless you have some custom logic in placed!! as I already answered execution will take place as per the order of execution specified by Salesforce.

Comment: ohh so basically i need to work around with custom logic only..!! thanx man..!!!

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can use that logic to skip the validation rule.